# How can i use my data from a api and pass it into another function for further processing

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

What method is there without using setTimeout() to allow data from the fetch to be stored in the stored_data array, then allowing the test function to manipulate.

So far i get undefined.

```
let stored_data = []


fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => stored_data.push(json))


function test(e) {
console.log(e)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply chain another `.then`. You also forgot to declare `store_data` as a variable

```
let stored_data = []

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => stored_data.push(json))
      .then( _ => {
          // array now ready for manipulation
      })
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but i wish to access the stored_data outside the function.

Comment: The problem is you can't. Either you chain it with `.then`, or you wrap it in an async function and await the fetch. Those are your two options.

Comment: oh ok thanks, i see so if i wanted another function to use the stored_data id have to call the async function with a .then inside of the newly function that wishes to use stored_data.

Comment: No. The only reason why you have to chain `.then` on fetch is because fetch itself is async. You must gurantee that by the time you access `stored_data`, fetch has already resolved, so you can do that by only accessing the `stored_data` when fetch has resolved, which can be done with `.then`.